# Githubの料金について

Tags: github

Githubのorganizationでプライベートリポジトリを作り、organizationのメンバーではなくリポジトリのコラボレーターとしてメンバーを参加させた場合、課金対象の人数にカウントされますか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Organization owners and members each fill a seat. If you've sent a pending invitation to a prospective organization member, the invitation will fill a seat.
>
> Outside collaborators and bot accounts will count toward your organization's total of paid seats if they are given access to a private repository.

https://help.github.com/articles/about-per-user-pricing/

コントリビュータがプライベートリポジトリのアクセス権を持っているなら課金の対象に含まれます。